# Angular2 Update function in main app component resets current Component

Tags: typescript, angular

I have app that looks like this:

#### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/router';
import { NgClass } from 'angular2/common';

import { FactoryService } from './factory.service';
import { FactoryComponent } from './factory.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'templates/app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NgClass],
  providers: [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    FactoryService
  ]
})
@RouteConfig([
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent
  },
  {
    path: '/factory',
    name: 'Factory',
    component: FactoryComponent
  }
])
export class AppComponent {
    currentTab: string = "dashboard";
    private factory;
    private updateFunc = setInterval(() => this.updateGame(), 1000 );

    constructor(
        private _factoryService: FactoryService){
            this.factory = this._factoryService.getFactory(1);
        }

    updateGame(){
        this.factory.update();
    }
}
```

#### factory.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from 'angular2/core';
import { Router } from 'angular2/router';
import { NgClass } from 'angular2/common';

import { Factory } from './factory';
import { FactoryService } from './factory.service';

import { Capitalize } from './capitalize.pipe';
import { MapToIterable } from './maptoiterable.pipe';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-factory',
    templateUrl: 'templates/factory.component.html',
    styleUrls:  ['css/factory.component.min.css'],
    directives: [NgClass],
    pipes: [Capitalize, MapToIterable]
})
export class FactoryComponent implements OnInit {

    factory: Factory;
    activeTab: string = "grinder";
    editingFactoryName: boolean = false;

    constructor(
        private _router: Router,
        private _factoryService: FactoryService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.factory = this._factoryService.getFactory(1);
    }
}
```

But then in my Factory component each time I try to do anything the UI is reseting, like if I press a tab to show something immediately returns to initial state and I can't navigate.

How can I implement an update function that updates the status of the APP withouth reseting current status?

I'm willing to post any more necessary code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes post some more relevant code.

Comment: It would be great from you to tell me what relevant code you need to better answer the question.

Comment: May be your factory service, ui part and how u use factory cmp.

Comment: updated the question with all the code

Comment: still its pretty confusing to me. But may be thats because you are playing with `setInterval` which updates something after every 1 sec.

Comment: Can't figure out how UI gets updated. what is `this.factory.update()` and `factory`. there are several confusions yet.  wait and some one could help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` from components:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'templates/app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NgClass],
  providers: [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    FactoryService
  ]
})
```

only add it to `bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);`

`ROUTER_PROVIDERS` need to be global, if you add it to a component, it gets  different (new) instances.

Comment: I did as you said but the UI is still resetting each second the function is executed.